# Correct form of an article in these sentences:

Tags: articles

I was just wondering if you could help me with the articles(the, a, an, nothing) in these sentences:

> 1) (The article) night is quiet. Let's go for a walk.
>
> 2) They are going to stay at (the article) hotel.

Comment: Please improve your questions.

Comment: @Lambie and could you explain how ?! I have written everything necessary for answering this questions.

Comment: You said: Can you help me with these sentences. ..../night is quiet/ is not a sentence. /The night is quiet/ is a sentence. a walk and an hotel. Even you say: A hotel. I would write an hotel.

Comment: You should say which one you think is correct and why you are not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The** night is quiet, let's go for a walk.

They point to the night at which they are speaking. It means the current night. The both  speaker and hearer know which night.

> They are going to stay at **a** hotel.

The hearer doesn't know which hotel, it could be any hotel and the speaker doesn't mind to say which hotel.

Answer (score 0):

Sentence #1:

> **The** night is quiet. Let's go for a walk.

It should be *the* because we're referring to the specific night when that conversation took place. Also, notice how I spelled *quiet*. *quiet* and *quite* are two different words that mean different things.

Sentence #2:

> They are going to stay at **a** hotel.

It should be *a* because we don't know which specific hotel they are going to stay at. They're just talking about any old hotel.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answers:

Without any more information about the hotel situation, **a hotel** is probably the article you want. It indicates that they're staying at some unspecified hotel. Just for example, if you were to say

> They are going to stay at **the** hotel

It would imply that the person speaking, and the person they're talking to, both know which hotel the speaker is referring to. Probably the same hotel that they are staying at. Hopefully that makes some sense